# Yum installation fails with RHEL 6.5

Tags: linux, yum, rhel6, packages

I am trying to install shibboleth SP package using YUM installation (Yum install shibboleth). I am getting the following error while installing.

```
Downloading Packages:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libcurl-    openssl-7.33.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-    6/x86_64/liblog4shib1-1.0.8-1.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned     error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libsaml8-2.5.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libxerces-c-3_1-3.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL  returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libxml-security-c17-1.7.2-2.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security%3A/shibboleth/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libxmltooling6-1.5.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL  returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error Downloading Packages:libxerces-c-3_1-3.1.1-2.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/libxerces-c-3_1- 3.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
liblog4shib1-1.0.8-1.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/liblog4shib1-1.0.8-1.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libcurl-openssl-7.33.0-1.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/libcurl-openssl-7.33.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libxml-security-c17-1.7.2-2.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/libxml-security-c17-1.7.2-2.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libsaml8-2.5.3-1.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/libsaml8-2.5.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libxmltooling6-1.5.3-1.1.x86_64: failure: x86_64/libxmltooling6-1.5.3-1.1.x86_64.rpm from security_shibboleth: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

What could be cause of this issue?. I installed it using the same commands in some other machines(It worked fine).

Comment: // , I found more about this here: https://community.hpcloud.com/article/centos-63-instance-giving-cannot-retrieve-metalink-repository-epel-error. I think the problem goes a little deeper than just some bad mirrors, since the mirrors should update anyway, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I identified the issue.

The mirror which is contacted by my machine is not containing the files requested.

So changing the base URL/Mirror list in the repository configuration is solved the issue.

Comment: This answer would have been much more useful to me if if you had included how to find out which part of the configuration was broken. As Aaron said, the 404 already tells me that the file is missing.

Answer (score 3):

If you get a 404 in your browser, [what does it mean](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)? It's the same thing here.

You have cached metadata about this repository that is no longer valid, or you have a network problem reaching the mirror. Start with a `yum clean all` and try again. If it still fails, start investigating the network stack. (Are you caching a bad DNS record on this host for download.opensuse.org, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, "yum clean all" helped me after 2 hours of searching for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Aravind's answer doesn't seem to be an answer at all. Here is the best answer I can provide:

Notice that the URL in the repo file (http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security://shibboleth/RHEL_5/security:shibboleth.repo or similar, depending on your platform) has a `:` in it, and notice that the error URL has that `:` replaced by `%3A`.

When you run the yum command, it displays a bunch of failed URL's, but if you literally copy and paste those URL's to curl or wget them, the files download just fine. So the files *are* on the server, but something in yum's processing of the URL doesn't like the URL format.

The only solution I know of right now is to copy/paste all the URL's to wget or curl, and then yum install the local rpm files.